# how to pass selected value from a @Html.Hidden as input parameter in @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have @Html.Hidden  : @Html.Hidden("Zpy_moisId", ViewBag.Zpy_moisId as object)
how can i pass parameter from @Html.Hidden  to actionlink

thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean pass a parameter to an action link?  An action link is just an a tag.    if you have a value that you are putting in the hidden field, why couldn't you just craft the hrf url yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still at ***server-side***, you could just use same ViewData.

```
@Html.Hidden("Zpy_moisId", ViewData["Zpy_moisId"])
@Html.ActionLink("Server-side Link", "About", "Home", new { id = ViewData["Zpy_moisId"] })
```

**Output**

```
<input id="Zpy_moisId" name="Zpy_moisId" type="hidden" value="123">
<a href="/Home/About/123">Server-side Link</a>
```

If you want to construct a link at ***client-side*** *based on other event such as button click*, you can use ***jQuery***.

```
@Html.Hidden("Zpy_moisId", ViewData["Zpy_moisId"])
<a id="sample-link">Client-side link</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#sample-link").attr("href", "@Url.Action("About", "Home")/" + 
           $("#Zpy_moisId").val());
    })
</script>
```

**Output**

```
<input id="Zpy_moisId" name="Zpy_moisId" type="hidden" value="123">
<a id="sample-link" src="/Home/About/123">Client-side link</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Zpy_moisId"] = "123";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult About(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```